# KendoUI listview passing IEnumerable<model> instead of model from editor template in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listview, kendo-ui, ienumerable, mvc-editor-templates

I've been puzzling over this for a few days now.  Basically, I have a view model that contains three IEnumerables of other view models to be displayed in three separate Kendo controls - one as a ListView, and two as GridViews.  Each view model has a separate editor template that is used by the corresponding control.  The GridViews are working 100%, and the Kendo ListView is working properly on the page (the ListView refreshes with the updated data).

**My problem is that an IEnumerable of the view model is being passed to the ActionResult (with a null value) instead of just a single instance of the view model, and the DataSourceRequest is empty.**

Here is the (redacted) code.

The view models (just the wrapper and view model for the ListView in question):

```
public class MainPersonViewModel
{
    public MainPersonViewModel(){}

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DetailsViewModel> PersonDetails { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AddressViewModel> Addresses { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PersonGroupingViewModel> MemberOf { get; set; }
}

public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public DetailsViewModel(){}

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string WorkingTitle { get; set; }
}
```

The Kendo ListView template:

```
@model Staff.ViewModels.MainPersonViewModel

<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="personDetailsTemplate">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name: </td><td>${Name}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Working Title: </td><td>${Title}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <div class="edit-buttons">
    <a class="k=button k-button-icontext k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span   class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit</a>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</script>
```

And the Kendo control itself:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<Staff.ViewModels.DetailsViewModel>(Model.PersonDetails)
.Name("personDetailsList")
.TagName("div")
.ClientTemplateId("personDetailsTemplate")
.Editable()
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(f => f.PersonId);
            m.Field(f => f.Name);
            m.Field(f => f.WorkingTitle);
        }
    )
    .Read(read => read.Action("ViewPersonDetails", "Staff", new {id = Model.PersonId}))
    .Update(update => update.Action("UpdatePersonDetails", "Staff"))
)
```

)

The ActionResult called by the Listview in the controller is as follows:

```
public class StaffController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult UpdatePersonDetails([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, IEnumerable<DetailsViewModel> toUpdate)
    {
        //update code here
        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    }
}
```

Finally the editor template (located in Views\Staff\EditorTemplates):

```
@model Staff.ViewModels.DetailsViewModel
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NameFirst)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NameFirst)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NameLast)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NameLast)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="edit-buttons">
                    <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-update-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-update"></span>Save</a>
                    <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-cancel-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-cancel"></span>Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Since the ListView seems to be refreshing I don't think it's necessarily a problem with it or the DataSource on the page, so I'm leaning towards some detail (i.e. limitation) with the editor template that I'm missing.  Any thoughts?

Sorry for the long post, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just an update: I never figured out the problem, but did get the Listview to work by scrapping the current view and re-building it by starting with the Listview before adding the Kendo grids to the page.  No changes were made to the editor templates or any of class files.